# Create abbreviation for function containing arguments

Tags: emacs, elisp, abbreviation

When I define a function using define-skeleton I'm able to create an abbreviation for it in my abbrev table through,

```
("abbrev_name" "" function_name nil)
```

However, if I use defun (which needs arguements), e.g.,

```
(defun function_name (arg)
   ""
   (interactive "sThe argument is")
   (insert arg)
 )
```

then I can still call it using "M-x function_name" but I'm not able to call it using an abbreviation (I get an error message pertaining wrong number of arguments). Is there a workaround that I can use here?

Comment: @Dan I tried to clarify it a little. Please let me know if its still unclear.

Comment: Maybe this deserves a `M-x report-emacs-bug` asking for abbrev to use `call-interactively` when the abbrev's hook is a command rather than just a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs is calling your function with 0 arguments

Instead of

`("abbrev_name" "" function_name nil)`

use this:

`("abbrev_name" "" (lambda () (call-interactively 'function_name)) nil)`

This way, emacs will prompt you to insert the string at the minibuffer.

Answer (score 0):

Let us start with your actual question:

```
(defun function-name ()
   (let ((arg (read-from-minibuffer ....)))
     ...))
```

Now, I think what you are looking for are [skeletons](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/autotype/).